# Arch Linux (k4.17) boot failure on Baytrail

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, grub, uefi, intel-graphics

I recently installed Arch Linux on one of the cheap windows tablet. I chose arch linux, because it had latest kernel, and in kernel 4.12 the rtl8723bs wifi driver was mainlined. I was surprised how well it petformed. But one thing keeps irritating me...

The tablet has Z3735G processor (x86_64 supported). But, it has the infamous 32-bit UEFI. I modified the installation media to include bootia32.efi and boot the grub cmdline, and then load the live iso. I had to restart the live iso few times, but there the problem started. The device often fails to boot the kernel. There are 3 types of the fail:

- Instant reboot after grub command `boot`
- Hang and then sudden reboot after `boot` command
- Kernel loaded, but after few messages the screen goes off [uncommon]
- Instead of kernel messages, screen starts flickefing with white horizontal strips [rare]

This problem persisted even after installation. I have tried numerous kernel arguments to supress this issue:

- `i915.modeset=0` No effect
- `i915.nomodeset=1` IDK if this is correct
- `nomodeset` No effect
- `add_efi_memmap` Though missing this would allow the kernel to overwrite EFI memory.
- `video=SVIDEO-1:d` No effect
- `acpi=off` No effect
- `noapic` No effect
- `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` added always, but the issue persists.

The kernel when the boot fails doesn't produce even single line of output, so I can't figure out what happened. Maybe it is problem that it boots 64-bit kernel form 32-bit grub&efi. Has anyone experienced/solved similar issue? Please, let me know.

System specs:

```
CPU: Intel Atom Z3735G @ 1.33GHz
GPU: Intel IGP
RAM: 1GB LDDR3
Flash: 16GB internal
```

**EDIT#1**
I think the reason is grub2 gfxterm mode setting. It may pass wrong value into linux, which then fails to boot. Booting in blind mode results in sucessful boot attempt.

Comment: Given your edit: did you try the grub2 `gfxmode text` command?

Comment: Yes, I did, and it broke the late kernel modesetting completely. There was a black screen after that.